# How to include column which is not a part of group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

How to get max of `w_cost` by `v_id` and also the final result set should include `av_id`.

```
s_id sg_id  r_cost  w_cost  av_id v_id
123  100    0.50    1.00    1     333
123  105    0.75    0.50    2     333
123  330    2.00    Null    3     888
```

If `w_cost` is NULL, `r_cost` should be taken. The final result should be:

```
s_id v_id   w_cost  av_id
123  333     1.00   1
123  888     2.00   3
```

Basic query is

```
SELECT
t.s_id,
sv.v_id,
sv.w_cost,
CASE
  WHEN sv.w_cost IS NULL THEN
    sv.r_cost::numeric
  ELSE sv.w_cost::numeric
  END AS cost
FROM test t
INNER JOIN stra_ven sv tmad ON
t.s_id = sv.s_id 
GROUP BY t.s_id,sv.v_id,sv.w_cost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Window Functions:**

This is what window functions are made for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

See the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b52e44f21eeedf431e23aaf82ecc5ad9)

```
SELECT 
    s_id, v_id, w_cost, av_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        s_id,
        v_id,
        av_id,
        COALESCE(w_cost, r_cost) as w_cost,                                    -- A
        MAX(COALESCE(w_cost, r_cost)) OVER (PARTITION BY v_id) as max_w_cost   -- B
     FROM testdata) s
WHERE 
    max_w_cost = w_cost                                                        -- C
```

A: `COALESCE` gives the first not `NULL` value in the list. So if `w_cost` is `NULL`, `r_cost` will be taken.

B: The window function `MAX()` gives the max value in the partition of `v_id`. The max function ueses the same `COALESCE` clause as in (A)

C: The `WHERE` clause filters the row where max equals the current value of `w_cost`.

If there are more rows with the same `MAX` value in my example you get all of them. If you just want one of them then you can add a column to the partition to make the window more precise. Or you can order by something and just take the first one or you take a more or less random one by `DISTINCT ON`.

---

**DISTINCT ON:**

With `DISTINCT ON` you can filter the distinct row for special columns (whereas the normal `DISTINCT` looks at all columns). Because a result set without any `ORDER BY` clause can be very random, it should be sorted by v_id and the final cost (greatest first (`DESC`); calculated with the `COALESCE` function as stated above). Then the `DISTINCT` takes the first row.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=09c76e903d0fcf4141faa504c6eab45a)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v_id)                  -- C
    s_id, v_id, cost as w_cost, av_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        s_id,
        v_id,
        av_id,
        COALESCE(w_cost, r_cost) as cost   -- A
     FROM testdata
     ORDER BY v_id, cost DESC) s           -- B
```

A: `COALESCE` as mentioned in the window function section.

B: Ordering to get the wanted row first.

C: `DISTINCT ON` filters for every distinct `v_id` the first row.

Comment: Thanks much ! My only concern is where clause because there are millions of rows and some of them will have matching max_w_cost . Is there any other way to get just 2 rows instead of 3 rows in results?

Comment: @sandy Yes, you could try it with `DISTINCT ON`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=09c76e903d0fcf4141faa504c6eab45a

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below might work:

```
with my_table as (
select 
   123 as s_id,
   100 as sg_id,
   0.50 as r_cost,
   1.00 as  w_cost,
   1 as av_id,
   333 as v_id
union all
   select 
    123 as s_id,
    105 as sg_id,
    0.75 as r_cost,
    0 as  w_cost,
    2 as av_id,
    333 as v_id
union all 
select 
   123 as s_id,
   330 as sg_id,
   1.00 as r_cost,
   Null as  w_cost,
   3 as av_id,
   888 as v_id
),
w_r_cost_table as (
select t.*,
        case 
            when t.w_cost is not null then t.w_cost
            else t.r_cost
        end as w_r_cost
        from my_table t
),
grouped_table as (
    select  
      A.v_id, 
      max(A.w_r_cost) as w_cost  
from w_r_cost_table A
group by A.v_id
)
select 
(select t.s_id from w_r_cost_table t where t.w_r_cost = g.w_cost and t.v_id = g.v_id) as s_id,
g.v_id,
g.w_cost,
(select t.av_id from w_r_cost_table t where t.w_r_cost = g.w_cost and t.v_id = g.v_id) as av_id

from grouped_table g
```

Let's assume that the temp table `my_table` is your source table. 
First, we should define the corrected values for the column `w_cost`. As in your question, we should not consider `null` values for `w_cost`.

To do this, I created a temp table called `w_r_cost_table`. Using "case when" we can make an if/else clause and put the corrected value in a new column called `w_r_cost`.

Then, using the temp table `w_r_cost_table`, we can perform a group by using the field `w_r_cost`, as done in `grouped_table`.

Finally, just make a select in `grouped_table` to have your results.

I used Postgres in this example.

Comment: Thanks for query.